# Easy way to get result of a test spec

Tags: scala, scalatest

I think I'm missing something obvious, is there a way to easily receive result of test run?

I'm running scalatest with simple `run(new my.TestClass)`

Is there any way to get the result of the test back? Or some way to run code after test failure?

Only way I found in scaladoc is running the tests with `Suite.run()` which returns Status, but it also needs Args, and I haven't found any example of what Args should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found execute on test failure functionality in documentation:

```
override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = {

    super.withFixture(test) match {
      case failed: Failed =>
        info("failed")
        //some code when tests fail
        failed

      case other => other
    }
  }
```

But I guess Args example would still be beneficial :)